# Acceptable Use of the goto Statement?

Tags: c

So, I made a console interface. It prompts users with several options they can enter. 1 for the first option, 2 for the second option, etc. Using the switch statement, each option will bring them to a different screen. Now, after any of the options are entered and the users are brought to a particular screen, how do I get them back to the selection screen with those options? Would it be acceptable for me to do something along the lines of

```
selectionScreen:

printf("Enter 1 for the First Screen\n");
printf("Enter 2 for the Second Screen\n");
printf("Enter 3 for the Third Screen\n\n");

scanf("%d", &selection);

switch (selection)
{

case 1:

    //do and print stuff here

    for (i = 0 ; ; i ++)
    {

        //do and print stuff here

        while(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_TAB))
        {

            goto selectionScreen;

        }

         printf("Enter the Tab key to go back the selection screen.\n\n");
         printf("Enter any key besides Tab to reload!\n\n");

         getchar();

         system("CLS");

     }

    break;

case 2:

    //do and print stuff here

    for (i = 0; ; i++)
    {

        //do and print stuff here

        while(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_TAB))
        {

            goto selectionScreen;

        }

         printf("Enter the Tab key to go back the selection screen.\n\n");
         printf("Enter any key besides Tab to reload!\n\n");

         getchar();

         system("CLS");

     }

    break;

case 3:

    //do and print stuff here

    for (i = 0 ; ; i++)
    {

        //do and print stuff here

        while(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_TAB))
        {

            goto selectionScreen;

        }

         printf("Enter the Tab key to go back the selection screen.\n\n");
         printf("Enter any key besides Tab to reload!\n\n");

         getchar();

         system("CLS");

     }

    break;

default:

    //do stuff here

}
```

Or is there a more favorable way of doing this

Comment: Just slap a `do while (true)` around the whole thing and replace your `goto`s with `break`s.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError actually he would remove the goto's and throw a break inside the single block that does not have a goto.

Comment: Wouldn't he need breaks to get out of his inner loops?

Comment: It seems to be becoming more fashionable these days to justify using `goto`, and to recommend its use to beginners. IMO it's better to avoid it entirely, and on those rare occasions where it might actually be justified, just make your code very slightly more verbose than it needs to be. If you try to justify it, then I think you'll end up just justifying it too much and thinking every time is an exception, and I think it's best not to go down that road.

Comment: I knew I'd be entertained by a `goto` question. What I find amusing is that `goto` generates so much ire in some people, and yet those same people often embrace exceptions, which are often little more than `goto`s with hidden destinations (not referring to anyone here). The `goto` has its place, which is usually bailing out of nested logic on error conditions (as in `goto Failure;`). But as a control flow mechanism? Bad idea in most cases.  But bailing out to a single error handling point is often a perfect solution that simplifies and enhances maintainability.

Comment: I agree with the reasoning @CareyGregory presented (+1). I might also add `break` and `continue` to the camp of "controlled goto work-arounds". You probably don't want to dive head first into using `goto` for your control, but rather use it on an exception basis.

Comment: All loops can be reduced to `if (condition) goto loop;`. The world's not going to end just because someone uses a `goto`, and people can write whatever code they please, but you can find "controlled goto work-arounds" under just about every rock you turn if you're determined to see them as such. A branch within a logical structure such as a loop or an exception block is not the moral equivalent of a bare unstructured `goto`, in my book, and I think it's misleading to describe them in that way in order to justify the practice.

Comment: No argument, but no one's trying to justify the practice of unstructured gotos.

Comment: @Paulgriffiths I am certsinly not trying to cast any dark shadows on constructs such as `break` or `continue` but just pointing out they provide a useful, controlled means of avoiding `goto` in ceryain situations.

Comment: @CareyGregory: OK, perhaps "the `goto` has its place" means something other than what I think it means, then, and describing exceptions as "often little more than `goto`s" is not meant to draw an analogy between the two. But either here or elsewhere, there seems to be an odd trend to justify them, lately. I'm not saying there can *never* be a place where a `goto` could make code more readable, just that there are many, many more places where they don't, and even when they look like they might, most of the time it's just a lazy way to avoid refactoring all that nested logic in the first place.

Comment: @mbratch: Sure. Ultimately, portability aside, *all* programming languages are little more than a "useful, controlled means of avoiding" all that messy, unstructured machine language, but not many people suggest going to back to machine language because it's all basically equivalent. Not saying *you're* doing this, but some people do make the 'exceptions and `break` are about the same as `goto`, so why not embrace it and be happy?' argument, which is odd to me.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths I see, and I do agree with you. I didn't intend that meaning at all. I intended the world "controlled" to be a very positive alternative to "uncontrolled", but I failed in being clear.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths - I never use `goto`s as a lazy way to avoid refactoring code.  I use them solely to improve the clarity and maintainability of code from the outset.  The flip side of the coin of this "trend" you perceive of justifying `goto` is the irrational religious holy war against `goto` that has been waged since Dijkstra's "Goto Considered Harmful" letter of 1968.  There is nothing whatsoever inherently wrong with the `goto` and no reason to refactor code just to avoid it.  What Dijkstra wrote about was the _misuse_ of `goto`, and _at the time_ he was right.  But that was then, not now.

Comment: @CareyGregory: You're welcome to your opinion, of course. If you think they "improve the clarity and maintainability of code", then it's your code, your rules. There's no "irrational religious holy war", though. It's just a bad programming practice, not a crime.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths - Declaring an element of the language a bad programming practice wholesale without regard for the context in which it's used is nothing but irrational.  But comments aren't the place for debate, so this will be my last response.  Enjoy your religion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm unsure if the posted code is exactly what's intended functionally, but the following would do the equivalent:

```
do
{
    printf("Enter 1 for the First Screen\n");
    printf("Enter 2 for the Second Screen\n");
    printf("Enter 3 for the Third Screen\n\n");

    scanf("%d", &selection);

    if ( selection < 1 || selection > 3 )
        break;

    switch (selection)
    {
    case 1:
        //do and print stuff here
        break;

    case 2:
        //do and print stuff here
        break;

    case 3:
        //do and print stuff here
        break;
    }
}
while ( GetAsyncKeyState(VK_TAB) );
```

I really can't remember the last time I used a `goto`. I think it was in a FORTRAN class.

Comment: @CareyGregory haha I wouldn't say that there's not some good uses for them. I'm sure you had a very good reason. And, OK, maybe I have, too, since the FORTRAN class. But I truly don't remember when it was exactly. :)

Comment: Thanks! My fault for being lazy when I wrote the example. Mostly because I was reading and writing from and to multi-level pointers. It wasn't representative of my actual code. Which is why I didn't get the exact answers I was looking for. I just edited it to what it should have been originally. However, what you wrote did really help me. I am now using an infinite do while loop and got rid of the goto 's. And thanks for the tip on the switch statement.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  It is acceptable.

You officially have permission to write code any way you want at any time.  There are generally several ways to do just about anything.   Your way works, and now you have valuable experience building control structures with gotos.  That experience will be valuable in the future because other programs use gotos.

That being said, **mbratch** has put together another way to do it.  I prefer his method, as it makes the code easier to read and maintain.

You should study and understand both techniques
.
Each technique is like an arrow.  You put them in your quiver, and can head off to hunt bigger game.   The more you know, the more dangerous you will be.

Comment: Anyone can write whatever code they wish, but the point of Code Review is to help you write _good_ code. Ever since Dijkstra's _Go to statement considered harmful_ essay ([ACM](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145%2F362929.362947) and widely reproduced elsewhere), programmers have accepted that `goto`s should be eliminated except where it is impractical to do so. Clearly this code easily can be restructured to eliminate the `goto`s, so most programmers would agree that a `goto`-free solution is superior.

Comment: I would encourage you to read "go to statement considered harmful considered harmful"